# UIImagePicker built with SDK 4.3 "Hangs" on iOS 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiimagepickercontroller

Has anyone experienced a problem with UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera built with SDK 4.3 "Hanging" on devices running iOS 4.2?

In my application, users running iOS 4.3 can open UIImagePicker and take photos.
If a user is running iOS 4.2, the UIImagePicker loads and shows the "shutter image", but the application hangs and the "shutter" never opens to display the camera's view.
Screen Image here:http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20056106/ImagePicker_Stuck.png

No CrashLog is produced, because the application is just stuck in the ImagePicker. The ImagePicker's "Cancel Button" and "Camera Button" are not enabled, so there is no way to dismiss the ImagePicker.

Has anyone experienced this type of issue?

Thank you,

Curt

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem to yours that I fixed.

In my case the hanging only occurred when running my app on the iPhone 5.0 Simulator. If I ran the app on the iPhone 4.3 Simulator UIImagePicker worked fine.

The issue was how I was dismissing the UIImagePickerController.

Original code in my UIImagePickerController delegate method

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{

    // Incorrect way of dismissing the uiImagepickerController
    // [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];

    // Correct way of dismissing
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];

    [picker release];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Omid! This was my problem too. Seems we can't use [picker parentViewController] anymore.

Comment: Looks like it, interesting that the Apple [Camera Programming](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/TakingPicturesAndMovies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010406-SW1) documentation hasn't been updated to reflect this change in iOS 5.

They continue to use [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];

Comment: For some reason, this code works *sometimes* (NOT SAFE - DO NOT USE)...    [self.imagePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; ... I don't know how this wound up in the controller or why it works... but DON'T USE IT! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, Omid!

Answer (score 0):

Update your device, or post your crash log. Try to reboot the device and close all other app from background. this should fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, @Control-V. Maybe "Crash" is not the right term. The application does not produce a CrashLog, because it simply "Hangs" in the imagePicker. I can check the iOS version prior to loading the ImagePicker and avoid the "Hang-up" by only setting the sourceType to UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera when running iOS 4.3, but that's not really a solution. Rebooting and closing other apps does not "fix" the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Omil's answer, check that these two things are correct:

1. Your `UIImagePickerController`'s delegate is not `nil` (if it's `nil`, then how can you dismiss it?)
2. The view controller you are calling `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` on to dismiss the `UIImagePickerController` is not `nil`, and the same one you presented the picker controller on in the first place with `presentModalViewController`.

The problem with XCode4.2 is it caused point 2 to start failing (`[picker parentViewController]` used to be a valid way to get the parent view controller, but now it's nil), which is why Omil's fix works for that particular case.